# Redirect 301 to old site

Tags: redirect, seo

I briefly explain my problem. 
I created a new site through wordpress that I have installed in the root (www.miosito.it);

To install the site I moved the old site in the old folder (www.miosito.it/old); the problem is that Google has already indexed in the past the old well site, and then I would do a 301 redirect from (www.miosito.it) to (www.miosito.it/old).

I thought since this is the html file to act in this way:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(. *)\. Htm http://www.miosito.it/old/$1.htm
```

but I get an error like

```
www .miosito.it / old / old / old / old / old.nomefile.htm
```

I noticed from various tests that the problem is that ending .htm .php fact if I replace it with no problems. 
How can I fix? 
Alternative solutions?

Thank you all

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect website error 404 set redirect 301 or url rewrite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38029914/redirect-website-error-404-set-redirect-301-or-url-rewrite)

Answer (score -1):

You are getting a redirect loop error because your Redirect pattern and target are indentical so You need to exclude the target uri from your pattern :

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^ /((?!old).*)\.Htm http://www.miosito.it/old/$1.htm
```

Clear your browser cache before testing this.